# js last array item is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a hangman game and in the beginning the game asks the user for the word. Once it has the word it fills the word letters one by one in an array using a for loop. Unfortunately the last array element is always undefined for some reason.
Code(JS):

```
for(i=0;i<word.length;i++)
{
    if(i == word.length - 1)
    {
        wordLettersLeft = word.length;
        $("#cEText").removeAttr("style");
        $(".characterEnter").removeAttr("style");
        $("#gBtn").text("Lopeta");
        gameStarted = true;
        pcArrayLength = pcArray.length;
        lives = 4;
        alert("Peli alkaa! Sinulla on " + lives + " yritystä jäljellä.");
        alert("Vihje: " + hint);
        alert("Sinulla on vielä " + wordLettersLeft + " arvattavaa kirjainta jäljellä.");
    }
    else
    {
        pcArray.push(word[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to run this code ? May be because you are not pushing it in `pcArray`

Comment: Your `if` block runs when you're on the last letter of the word. But you only add to `pcArray` in the `else` block.

Comment: it _undefiend_ just because you not add it to `pcArray`

Comment: Wont it be easier to just split the word in its letters by using `.split('')` ? Then you can just write all the code that happens at the end after you split the string into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a very simple reason: you are not adding the last letter to your `pcArray`. Let's assume our word is 'bird' (because bird *is* a word). Your code would go through the letters b, i and r and push those to your array, so far so good. But when it hits the d, it is at position `word.length-1` - because the array length starts at 1 but the index starts at 0. Your `if` statement prevents it from pushing the last letter to the word. There are two solutions:

First, you could simply remove the `else` statement:

```
for(i=0;i<word.length;i++){
    if(i == word.length - 1){
        wordLettersLeft = word.length;
        $("#cEText").removeAttr("style");
        $(".characterEnter").removeAttr("style");
        $("#gBtn").text("Lopeta");
        gameStarted = true;
        pcArrayLength = pcArray.length;
        lives = 4;
        alert("Peli alkaa! Sinulla on " + lives + " yritystä jäljellä.");
        alert("Vihje: " + hint);
        alert("Sinulla on vielä " + wordLettersLeft + " arvattavaa kirjainta jäljellä.");
    }
    pcArray.push(word[i]);
}
```

That will push every letter every time! However, There is a more efficient way:

```
  for(i=0;i<word.length;i++)
      pcArray.push(word[i]);
  wordLettersLeft = word.length;
  $("#cEText").removeAttr("style");
  $(".characterEnter").removeAttr("style");
  $("#gBtn").text("Lopeta");
  gameStarted = true;
  pcArrayLength = pcArray.length;
  lives = 4;
  alert("Peli alkaa! Sinulla on " + lives + " yritystä jäljellä.");
  alert("Vihje: " + hint);
  alert("Sinulla on vielä " + wordLettersLeft + " arvattavaa kirjainta jäljellä.");
```

This way you will only execute your initial code *once* instead of checking the `if` every time. You *know* your loop will only run for as long as there are letters, so why even bother with the if?

As @Shilly mentions in the comments, you can forego the for loop altogether by doing this:

```
pcArray = word.split('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say someone's inputing the word "Test". For `i === 3` which is the last iteration, you enter the `if` clause and you're missing out on the `else` clause, which is where you're doing:

```
pcArray.push(word[i]);
```

What you want is to do this anyway, regardless of whether you're in the `if` or the `else`, so you can just drop the `else` clause and do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The last step of your loop does not execute `pcArray.push(word[i]);`. So obvioulsy, the last value is missing.

But if you want to convert a string into an array, just do this :

```
var pcArray = word.split('');
```